# Is it possible to use signal level as signalisation for AEX2400 board in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I want to be able to use signal level on an analog line to be able to generate valid call via a AEX2400 with FXO modules.

To understand better my question, lets say I have hooked up a smartphone to the first channel of the board. I want Asterisk to receive a call when the RX level go over the defined level (of if not possible if there is activity detection).

Is it possible ?

Comment: It is hardware/firmware level for board, not asterisk.

Comment: I don't doubt of that, this is a dahdi config step, but I didn't find a dahdi tag

Comment: Not think dahdi driver have something like that. Usually on-hook/off-hook is just diode+resistance on board which result on/off level on some board leg. i.e not fixable for sure without change of board and know how board designed.

Comment: Indeed, I have asked for digium support, and told me that this could not be done without a lot of work on both the board dans dahdi drivers.